# Powershell using SimplySql script for querying MySQL database

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am totaly new to Powershell (5.1) and follwed  tutorials in youtube and brief description on https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2019/07/how-to-query-a-mysql-database-with-powershell/

which would solve my problem.

But I am unable to install SimplySql on my notebook (win 10).

What I did: downloaded script-folder in \program files\windowspowershell\modules\SimplySql\
I can find it when using -Listavailable  command but cannot install it.
I suppose that the standard security settings of client prohibits it.

Please instruct me how I can make this script (and maybe even others) run.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question and explain how you cannot install the module. Is there an error message? What does it say? Something else?

Comment: No erro, no message just the cursor at the next line. But when I enter "Get-Module SimplySQL" I receive nothing! Open-MySQLConnection xyz... brings me an error message theat the cmdlet was not found. So it is not installed properly. I used PS as Administrator to try to install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you - new to Powershell, followed the exact same tutorial you did.  Install-Module worked to download the module (which you did manually), but it wouldn't be listed as available or usable. No errors returned or indicated, even when using the -Verbose flag.

However, manually importing the module (once downloaded) worked, allowing me to use it.  Here's the command (adjust for your local system, as necessary):

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SimplySql\1.6.2\SimplySql.psm1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the module is downloading but not importing. I have only had this happen with the `SimplySql` module, but importing it after downloading fixes the issue with the module.

You can ask PowerShell to import all modules by running the script below. This will load all modules in all paths known to PowerShell.

```
$path = Get-Item (Get-Module -ListAvailable).Path
$fullpath = (Get-ChildItem ($path.PsParentPath) | Where {$_.Name -Like "*.psm1"}).FullName 

foreach ($item in $fullpath)
{
    Import-Module $item | Out-Null
}
```